# Cannot access a flavor class in a common class

Tags: android, gradle

I have an project that has:

```
  |--src/
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--MyActivity.java
      |--res/
      |  |--layout/
      |  |  |--activity_main.xml
      |  |--...
      |--AndroidManifest.xml
    |--flavor1/
      |--java/
      |  |--Activity1.java
      |--res/
         |--layout/
         |  |--activity1.xml   
    |--flavor2/
      |--java/
      |  |--Activity2.java
      |--res/
         |--layout/
         |  |--activity2.xml
```

I selected option from `BuildVariants` as `flavor1` - but I can't acces class `Activity1` from `MyActivity`. Is there a way to handle it, or I am missing smth?

Project structure in Android Studio:
[image]

gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my_path.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.10"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            applicationId "com.flavo1.name"
        }

        flavor2 {
            applicationId "com.flavo2.name"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: you can not until you add `flavor1` as a module project to main..!! can i see your build.gradle??

Comment: Add `flavor1` into `productFlavors` in your `build.gradle` and don't forget to `import` the class `Activity1` in `MyActivity`. Also please check if your class path is correct

Comment: @ jayatubi my `flavor1` is already aded into `productFlavors` but what do wou mean by " class path is correct "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must maintain the same project structure in all your flavors exactly like in \main directory. For Example:

```
 |--src/
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--com/
      |     |--my_project/
      |        |--my_name/
      |           |--MyActivity.java

      [...]

    |--flavor1/
       |--java/
       |  |--com/
       |     |--my_project/
       |        |--my_name/
       |           |--Activity1.java

      [...]


    |--flavor2/
      |--java/
       |  |--com/
       |     |--my_project/
       |        |--my_name/
       |           |--Activity2.java


      [...]
```